# Analyzing clock oscillator using timing diagram

Tags: digital-logic, oscillator, clock, synchronous

In a recent examination a friend of mine was asked to analyze and find the frequency of oscillation of a clock oscillator using timing diagram as shown below:

[image]

Can someone give me directions as how to attack such problems?

The question is given in [An Engineering Approach to Digital Design," by William I. Fletcher](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/An_engineering_approach_to_digital_desig.html?id=WQdTAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) ques. no. is 5-18

Comment: When trying to solve exercises it's good practice to attempt solving them yourself and explaining what's your best guess.

Answer (score 3):

Leaving you to answer the question here's a couple of heavy hints.

There are two major clues in the question that give the answers to this question.

(1) Each gate has a propagation **delay of 30nS** so if **there are 3 gates in series** what is the total time delay between the input and output? This will give **half the pulse period**. (the time taken to change from a '0' at the input to a '1' at the output or a '1' at the input to a '0' at the output). So the **total period** of the oscillator will be 2 x 3 x 30 (in nS). Knowing the period you can easily calculate the frequency ( F = 1/T) where F is in Hertz and T in Seconds)

(2) **The gates uses are INVERTERS and there is an ODD NUMBER of inverters in the chain**. This means that the output is complimentary (i.e. opposite, negated or 180 degree phase shifted) to the input. This produces an unstable 'race' condition in the logic. When the output '1' is fed back to the input this will produce a '0' output after the gate delay. This will then produce a '1' output after another gate delay and so on. The gates never settle into a stable state.  If an EVEN NUMBER of gates were used in the delay chain there would be no race condition and no oscillation.

The final gate is a simple buffer and simply inverts the oscillation and gives it another 30nS delay.

Comment: Oh that makes it too easy :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have any clue about where to start?

Hint: try to determine the logic steady states of the circuit, that is, all the possible input/state/output configurations. How many did you find? Note that Out(Q3)=In(Q1)

Do you notice any behavior that is incompatible with typical use of digital logic?

Drawing the timing diagram, a good way to start is to set all the signals to a certain value (say, 0) at time 0, and see how they change afterwards.

Once you have done that, how long does it take to a signal to travel through the three inverters and back?